# "Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of undefined" gets thrown in one call, but not in another (and they're pretty much next to each other)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension, one chrome.runtime.sendMessage() call is problematic while others work; it's strange because the "problem" call is the exact same as the other, and invoked barely 5 lines away from it. Any possible explanations?

Here's the sendMessage() calls in my background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg)
{
    ...
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(timeCount); //not problematic
  }
  else if(msg == "NEED WATCHLIST")
  {
    chrome.runTime.sendMessage(timeCount); //throws error
  }
});
```

Here's the messaging from my popup.js that triggers the .addListener in background.js :

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("NEED TIME");

document.getElementById("settings").onclick = function()
{
     ...   
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("NEED WATCHLIST");
}
```

Here's my manifest.json for good measure (probably not relevant at all lol):

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Drill Sergeant",
  "description": "Regulates time spent on Facebook and YouTube",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "browser_action": {"default_popup": "popup.html", "default_icon": "images/icon128.png"  },
  "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "webNavigation", "notifications", "tabs", "background", "webRequest"],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["censor.html"]
}
```

Thanks guys, I really don't know how to go about this... (What even triggers the "Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of undefined" error in the first place?)

Comment: We're probably going to need to see the other "barely" 5 lines of code. Can you share the entire callback please?

Answer (score 0):

chrome.run`T`ime is your problem. You want chrome.run`t`ime (lower case 't')